# Cannot rewrite subterm in Coq

Tags: coq, proof

I have a proof in Coq where one of the hypothesis is:

```
H : m = pred q * n + (r + n)
```

And I have a proven lemma which states:

```
Lemma suma_conmutativa: forall m, forall n, m + n = n + m.
```

Where + is Notation for a function called suma that I defined:

```
Fixpoint suma (m:nat) (n:nat) : nat :=
match m with 
  | 0 => n
  | S k => S (suma k n)
end.
Notation "m + n" := (suma m n).
```

For some reason when I try to rewrite `suma_conmutativa with r n in H` I get the following error:

```
Error: Found no subterm matching "r + n" in H.
```

However, there clearly is a subterm matching r + n in H. Why can't Coq find it?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be a porblem with Notation because if H was m = pred q * n + (suma r n) then apparently it would be able to rewrite it.

Comment: Yes, are you sure the + in your expression is your `suma` ? Trying `Unset Printing Notations` (or equivalent in your IDE) to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert of notations in Coq, but here is how I understand your problem.

Coq replaces the first occurrence of `+` with `suma`. `suma` binds its arguments to scope `nat_scope`. Classic notation `+` is bound to `nat_scope` and is prefered for the second occurrence of `+`.

The solution I propose is to bound your notation to `nat_scope` to completely hide the original notation. This gives:
`Notation "m + n" := (suma m n) : nat_scope`.